# How to pad blocks across segments in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, bootloader, osdev

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
_TEXT16 SEGMENT USE16 'CODE'
_start:
    ; some code...
; add padding
byte 512-($-_start) dup (0)    ; works fine
_TEXT16 ENDS

_TEXT32 SEGMENT USE32 'CODE'
; some code
byte 1024-($-_start) dup (0)    ; error A2192: Operands must be in same segment
_TEXT32 ENDS
```

In NASM you would just do something like this `times 1024-($-$$) db 0`, but unfortunately the `$$` is not supported in MASM or in JWASM, which is what I'm using at the moment. I need this to align the blocks of my bootloader to the size of readable disk sectors.

So, my question is, how do I add padding of 512 bytes to my code blocks in MASM?

Edit:

The scenario has changed a bit.

```
_TEXT16 SEGMENT USE16 'CODE'
_start:
    ; some code...
_TEXT16 ENDS

_TEXT32 SEGMENT USE32 'CODE'
; some code
_TEXT32 ENDS

_TEXT64 SEGMENT USE64 'CODE'
; some code

; add padding
byte 510-($-_start) dup (0)    ; error A2192: Operands must be in same segment
dw 0AA55h
_TEXT64 ENDS
```

Now how would I go about adding the correct padding here?

Comment: Put a label at the start of the second sector as well.

Comment: Do you need the second segment to end 1024 bytes after the *start* of the first?  IDK if there's a way to make that an absolute thing; as Jester says, you could change to making the 2nd segment pad itself out to a size of 512 bytes.  And since you know the first sector did that, too, you'll end up at the right place.  The only difference is possible future maintenance, like if you put a new section between them.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I Just always found it practical. MASM from my point of view is closer to C than the regular assembly with NASM. It has a lot of convenience macros like `INVOKE`, or the ability to use `STRUCT` and `TYPEDEF`. My favourite and the main reason why I wanted to use it, other than just as an experiment, is because of `PROC` and `ENDP` I love, not having to write the code that makes a stack frame every time and being able to define what parameters the procedure takes, what registers it uses and local variables is just great.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh, and by the way, yes I am on windows. And we have had the honours before, but I used a different account back then. ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19782596/florian-schumacher))

Comment: @MichaelPetch Hope you remember me in a good way.

Comment: In your final scenario, can you use the sizes of the other segments, like `byte 510 - sizeof _TEXT16 -($-_start) dup (0)` or something like that to also subtract the lengths of the previous segments?  I have no idea if MASM allows that; sounds like a pain.  That wouldn't account for padding between segments if there is any to align their starts.

Comment: Perhaps use `org 510` or `org 510 + 7C00h` to seek to that point?  I think MASM ORG actually *can* do that, unlike NASM's.  NASM's docs specifically mention that it doesn't support the kind of trickery MASM's `org` directive allows, which implies that it is usable for this: https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.1.1

Comment: It's not like `invoke` is that great; it probably only knows how to do stack args which makes things inefficient in a tight bootloader.  If you don't care about efficient code-gen and have enough code for things like that to matter, use a C compiler.  You can use comments to annotate your code with any assembler, recording inputs / outputs / clobbers.  MASM `uses` just makes the compiler emit push/pop instructions, which you don't always want; normally you want to let functions clobber 2 or 3 scratch registers instead of using so many push/pop insns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a difficult one to explain but I finally solved my problem.

The code that ended up working was this:

```
.386P
.model TINY, C

_TEXT16 SEGMENT BYTE USE16 'CODE'
org 07C00h
begin16:

_start:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov bp, 07C00h
    mov sp, bp

    mov ah, 0Eh
    mov al, 'A'
    mov bl, 0Fh
    int 10h

    cli
    hlt

end16:
size16 equ end16 - begin16
_TEXT16 ENDS

_TEXT32 SEGMENT BYTE USE32 'CODE'
begin32:

start_protected_mode:
    cli
    hlt

end32:
size32 equ end32 - begin32
_TEXT32 ENDS

.x64
_TEXT64 SEGMENT BYTE USE64 'CODE'
begin64:

start_long_mode:
    cli
    hlt

end64:
size64 equ end64 - begin64
_TEXT64 ENDS

_BOOTDATA SEGMENT BYTE 'DATA'
begin_data:

bootDisk db ?

end_data:
size_data equ end_data - begin_data
_BOOTDATA ENDS

_PADDING SEGMENT BYTE
org (510 - size16 - size32 - size64 - size_data)                ; either of these work
;byte (510 - size16 - size32 - size64 - size_data) dup(0)       ; either of these work
dw 0AA55h
_PADDING ENDS

END _start
```

What's happening here is as follows. The first `org` directive (`org 07C00h`) sets the starting address of the program. It only does that because we have told it with the use of the `END` directive, that we have given a label to the start of our code (`END _start`). If you don't give the `END` directive a stating label of your code, the first `org` directive will just be resolved as a lot of zeros prepending your actual code. Or in short, it will actually offset your code by whatever value you give it.

The second `org` directive (`org org (510 - size16 - size32 - size64 - size_data)`) however acts like an offset, even if you don't give a label to the `END` directive.

Taking all of that into consideration and our result looks like this:

```
00000000  33C0              xor ax,ax
00000002  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000004  8EC0              mov es,ax
00000006  8ED0              mov ss,ax
00000008  BD007C            mov bp,0x7c00
0000000B  8BE5              mov sp,bp
0000000D  B40E              mov ah,0xe
0000000F  B041              mov al,0x41
00000011  B30F              mov bl,0xf
00000013  CD10              int 0x10
00000015  FA                cli
00000016  F4                hlt
00000017  FA                cli
00000018  F4                hlt
00000019  FA                cli
0000001A  F4                hlt
0000001B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000001D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000001F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000021  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000023  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000025  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000027  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000029  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000002B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000002D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000002F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000031  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000033  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000035  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000037  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000039  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000003B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000003D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000003F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000041  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000043  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000045  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000047  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000049  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000051  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000053  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000055  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000057  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000059  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000061  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000063  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000065  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000067  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000069  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000071  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000073  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000075  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000077  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000079  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000081  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000083  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000085  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000087  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000089  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000091  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000093  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000095  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000097  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000099  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009F  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000EB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000ED  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000EF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FF  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000101  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000103  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000105  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000107  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000109  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000111  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000113  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000115  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000117  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000119  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000121  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000123  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000125  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000127  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000129  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000131  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000133  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000135  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000137  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000139  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000141  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000143  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000145  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000147  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000149  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000151  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000153  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000155  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000157  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000159  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000161  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000163  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000165  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000167  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000169  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000171  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000173  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000175  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000177  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000179  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000181  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000183  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000185  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000187  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000189  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000191  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000193  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000195  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000197  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000199  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019F  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001EB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001ED  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001EF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001FB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001FD  0055AA            add [di-0x56],dl
```

As you can see I had to calculate the size of each segment by using labels at the beginning and end of it. I then set some constants to those sizes. If you ask yourself, why didn't I just put one label at the start and one at the end of my code? Then I have to tell you, that you can only put labels in segments and can only access them from within the same segment. Hence the constants, calculating the sizes for each one.

So in conclusion:

- The first `org` sets the program offset if you give `END` a label to the start of your code
- All following `org` directives will act as offsets, no matter what
- Align your `SEGMENT`s to `BYTE`s
- And do some constant label calculation hackery to get the right offset

Please don't completely take my word for this. This is only the result of many tests. If you have questions, please feel free to comment.

Otherwise, I hope that this helps whoever finds this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `org 510` or `org 510 + 7C00h` to seek to that point?

NASM's docs specifically mention that NASM doesn't support the kind of trickery MASM's `org` directive allows, which implies that MASM's `org` *is* usable for this. The NASM docs even [show a MASM example](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdo13.html#section-13.1.3):

```
; MASM example from the NASM manual
        ORG 0 

        ; some boot sector code 

        ORG 510 
        DW 0xAA55
```

I don't know how this might interact with multiple segments.  The OP reports that this only works with both `org` directives *inside* the same segment.  Perhaps there's a way to specify an origin for a segment as part of declaring it?

---

Or perhaps another option, can you ask MASM to calculate the size of those earlier segments in the case where you're not padding them to fixed sizes?  (When the sizes are fixed, things are obviously simple: you just make the second segment 512 bytes, following the first 512-byte segment, so it will end at 1024.)

Like `byte 510 - sizeof _TEXT16 -($-_start) dup (0)` or something like that to also subtract the lengths of the previous segments?  I have no idea if MASM allows that.  Apparently that doesn't work, so **perhaps define an `equ` or `size16 = $-start16` or something inside each of the two earlier segments.**

Either way that wouldn't account for padding between segments, if there is any to align their starts.

---

Or of course you could always append a boot signature to the assembler's flat binary output separately, as part of the build process, if you can't figure out how to get the assembler to do it for you.

In a Linux shell, this command opens `boot.bin`, seeks to byte 510, and writes `db 0x55, 0xaa`

```
echo -ne '\x55\xAA' | dd of=boot.bin conv=notrunc bs=2 count=1 seek=$((510/2))
```

If you're stuck using Windows, there is port of `dd`, for example http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.src.zip  If you aren't using a shell like `bash` or `zsh` to expand `$((510/2))`, that's just `seek=255` because `dd` takes seeks as a number of blocks, not bytes.  And I don't know how to pipe arbitrary binary data on Windows; perhaps with `python` if you have it installed, or just create a 2-byte file using an assembler.

```
dd.exe if=aa55.bin of=boot.bin conv=notrunc bs=2 count=1 seek=255
```

Comment: The approach with `org 0` `org 510` would work, but every time I have to jump to a label or access a variable, I'd have to add an offset of `07C00h` to it and that would be too tedious.

Comment: @AlbertWesker: Does it not work to use `org 7C00h` at the top, and `org 7C00h + 510` at the end, like I suggested in the first line of the answer?  Or you could just set segment registers to `07C0h` to match an ORG setting of `0`; that should only take one extra byte of code size at the top of the bootloader (`mov ax, 07C0h` vs. `xor ax,ax`).

Comment: If do that then the output suddenly looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/6cVqv2y9).

Comment: In addition to my first comment. It only works if both `org` statements are in the same segment.

Comment: @AlbertWesker: Sounds like MASM/JWASM is a huge pain for this, vs. the ease of NASM.  Or maybe there's a convenient way to do things we just don't know about. Did the other idea, in the 2nd half of my answer, pan out at all?  Does `sizeof` work on segment names?

Comment: Or of course you could always append a boot signature to the assembler's flat binary output separately, as part of the build process.  Like `echo -ne '\x55\xAA' | dd of=boot.bin conv=notrunc bs=2 count=1 seek=$((510/2))`

Comment: As an answer to the `sizeof` question. Unfortunately not.

Comment: @AlbertWesker: BTW, your bootloader is buggy: the instruction after `mov ss, ax` doesn't set a new SP to match it.  `mov` to `ss` only holds off interrupts until after the very next instruction, so you need to put those instructions back to back to atomically set a new SS:SP without risk of an interrupt handler using new-SS:old-SP.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but that was just an example to show you the problem, not my actual code.

Comment: The OP is on Windows, so using linux command line from a Windows shell will not be very useful. In my comments 2 days ago (I deleted them since no one was taking me seriously) I suggested the best course of action is to do padding outside of MASM and build the disk image with something like DD for Windows (http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.src.zip ) because I know what you are doing is very difficult in MASM. Split the bootloader and other code into separate ASM files, The bootloader can handle the padding fine.

Comment: @AlbertWesker you can spend a whole lot of time and pain working on this. MASM has a lot of deficiencies, and workarounds are very very hackish for this. I personally think you are going down a dark path by continuing to try and get this to work. I recommend taking the approach in my last comment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Maybe I'm mixing this up with a different querent, but I thought someone recently was asking about using JWASM on Linux because they liked MASM syntax so much.  In any case, it's just an example, and I described what it did in terms of open + seek.  If other Windows users want to adapt it, I was assuming they'd probably have Windows `dd` for writing boot sectors to floppy images anyway.  Maybe I should avoid `$((510/2))` arithmetic expansion in case some Windows users don't have MinGW or cygwin bash/zsh.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm about to throw this whole Idea out the window and use NASM for my bootloader instead. MASM/JWASM have their strengths but not for this.

Comment: @AlbertWesker : which was why I asked (in comments I deleted) why you wanted to use MASM instead of NASM. I'd highly recommend using NASM or even FASM (if you wanted). Trust me, such a move would be better.

Comment: Well then. Consider this a dead end. I had hoped that MASM would be able to achieve this, but lesson learned. Thanks for all of your help. I'm sure I'll be back soon with other problems. :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'd assumed MASM and/or JWASM would be able to do this somehow; kind of surprised if they really can't calculate sizes for you, not even if you manually use `size16 = end16 - start16` or something, subtracting labels you manually set!  I just posted this answer to give a pointer to some things to experiment with; I figured someone else would either comment with a correction or post their own answer with a working version.

Comment: Sadly, you can't use labels across segments, otherwise, this would have been very possible.

Comment: @AlbertWesker: `size16 = end-start` isn't a label, it's a numeric constant you'd define from the distance between two labels inside your `_TEXT16` segment.  (And do the same thing for a `size32 = end32 - start32`.)  If you mean that even `equ` / `=` constants aren't accessible outside the same segment, that's weird.

Comment: Wait, I'll quickly test that

Comment: Succes! Here, have an answer.

Comment: @AlbertWesker: Ok good, glad one of my initial ideas turned out to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It took a while but we got there.